# Numbers: How do I refer entire rows in different sheets?

Tags: macos, numbers, iwork

I am trying to create a table that contains all entries from other sheets in the numbers file. In all of these other sheets, the structure will be identical.

The reason for why I do this, is because the main table entries have to be sorted by sheet, whereas I wanna be able to just *add* new rows in a given sheet, without having to add rows in the main sheet.

This is entire thing is a table intended to contain chronological entries for a given client, but it needs to be sorted by client, when working with clients though, it makes sense to add a new entry at the bottom as a new entry. If I do it all in one table, I have to constantly shift things around.

I have no idea how to do this and this turns out to be very difficult to google, maybe numbers also just *can't* do that, that'd also be valuable to know. Thanks!

Comment: Though it does not sound like this is what you need, you can refer a number of rows in other tables or sheets in their entireties in Numbers formulas. Otherwise, the section on "Refer to Cells in Formulas" within the "[Calculate values using data in table cells in Numbers on Mac](https://support.apple.com/et-ee/guide/numbers/tan727173a8/mac)" Apple Support webpage gives more details on how to refer to whole rows in formulas. Let me know if you have any questions on that. If not, I think your best bet is to copy & paste the new rows in each table manually to the main table.

Comment: But is there a way to refer to _all_ rows? As in, when I write the formula that looks up the rows, I don't know what the end row will be.

Comment: You can refer to all of the existing rows in a table while creating a formula but it is not possible to write the formula such that it includes all future rows in that table. However, the formula can expand automatically if you insert the new rows among the rows that are already in the formula.